# $ _SESSION is not initialized - PHP

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a page where I run three checks on a form:

1) I select the user id (ID_Collaboratore) from his table when the email corresponds to the variable $ email, if the email does not exist I send out an error message

2) If the email is associated with a registered user then I check the token entered by the user, where if the token has been used (SI), then an error message is issued, otherwise I change that token from NO (not used) to SI (used), making the update and send it to the second page. Now the problem starts here.

What interests me:
case: User with existing email, enter tokens that can be used, change the token change from NO to YES,
creation of the $ _SESSION ['collab_tkn'];

Because in the page where the user is sent back there will be a check of $ _SESSION, where if the $ _SESSION is equivalent to that of the previous page, it can display the content of the page, otherwise it will be sent to the index page

code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["collab_tkn"])){
include('error_reporting.php'); ?>
<!--Inserisci Codice-->
<?php }else{ 
header("Location: index.php?ut=N");?>
<?php } ?>
```

code about my php script for the form:

```
<?php 
                 include('errore_reporting.php');
                $messaggio = "";
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
                {
                    include 'connection/cnt.php';
                    $token = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['rec_token']);
                    $utilizzato = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['utilizzato']);
                    $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

                    $controllo_collab = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT ID_Collaboratore FROM collaboratori WHERE email='".$email."'");
                    $verifica=mysqli_num_rows($controllo_collab);

                    if($verifica==0)  
                    {
                    $messaggio = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                     Attenzione si &egrave; tentato di utilizzare un email inesistente. 
                                  </div>';
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        $valori = $controllo_collab->fetch_array();
                        $_SESSION['collab_tkn'] = $valori['ID_Collaboratore'];

                        $query = $connessione->query("SELECT  utilizzato FROM token_rec_cred WHERE rec_token='$token'");
                        $data = $query->fetch_array();
                        $_SESSION['tkn_rec_cred'] = $data['utilizzato'];

                        if ($_SESSION['tkn_rec_cred'] == 'SI' )
                        {
                            $messaggio = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                Attenzione si &egrave; tentato di utilizzare un Token gi&agrave; usato. 
                              </div>';
                        } 

                        if ($_SESSION['tkn_rec_cred'] == 'NO' )
                        {

                          $connessione->query("UPDATE token_rec_cred SET utilizzato='$utilizzato' WHERE rec_token='$token'");
                          header('Location: rec_cred.php?tokn=Y');
                        } 
                     }                   

                 }
                if ($messaggio != "") echo $messaggio; 
                ?>
```

at present the problem is in this piece of code between the query and the initialization of the $ _SESSION, that is:

```
$controllo_collab = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT ID_Collaboratore FROM collaboratori WHERE email='".$email."'");
$verifica=mysqli_num_rows($controllo_collab);
```

and

```
$valori = $controllo_collab->fetch_array();
$_SESSION['collab_tkn'] = $valori['ID_Collaboratore'];
```

even if initialized when the user is redirected to the second page, it always gives me a fake and sends it back to me in index, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get the problem correctly. When your second snipped is the `index.php`, then you have to call `session_start()` again.

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.
>   [Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

So you have to call `session_start()` on every call to resume the session.

```php
include('errore_reporting.php');
session_start(); // Important!
$messaggio = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    // ... The rest of your code
```

Comment: my friend from this I realize that I'm very tired hahahahahahha, thank you so much, I knew the code was correct, but I didn't understand why it didn't work, but loving the code is also this